# Encountering 'Expected Type Expression but received "property" ' when defining instance variable type in Class

Tags: python, mypy, typechecking

I want to declare instance variables in the body of a Class `Baz` in order to add typehints to another function `Foo` that returns variables of said types.

The class is largely a wrapper, and looks something like this:

```
Class BazWrapper:

    def __init__(self, number, bar):

        bz = bar.get_baz(number)

        self.title = bz.title
        self.location = bz.location
        self.is_bazable = bz.bazable
```

Following the [Typehints Cheatsheet](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cheat_sheet_py3.html) from MyPy, I have tried to declare the instance variables in the class body in order to type them. I am trying to set them

```
Class BazWrapper:

    title: baz.title #Expected Type Expression but received "property"

    def __init__(self, number, bar):

        bz = bar.get_baz(number)

        self.title = bz.title
        self.location = bz.location
        self.is_bazable = bz.bazable
```

Alright, reasonable enough. So I tried to get the type of the property by wrapping it.

```
title: type(baz.title) 
#type() call should not be used in type annotation Use Type[T] instead
```

Again, reasonable, so I did.

```
title: Type[baz.title] #Expected Type Expression but received "property"
```

Back to square one.

On some level I get what is happening here, the error message is clear and I know that a property is a method attached as an attribute.
Also, I have a workaround, I *could* just do `title: string` and call it a day.
But since I do not have control of Baz, there is this little voice in the back of my head that says "What if `baz.title` changes? Where will your hardcoded types be then?"

So, where do I go from here? **Is it possible to use the type of a property as a typehint?**
If not, what is the best course of action going forward to get BazWrapper typed?

Comment: No, you can only use actual type as a hint, nothing like weird `typeof foo['propName']` or index types `SomeType['propName']` in TS exists in python.